# TFS commits to itself with powershell

Tags: c#, git, visual-studio, tfs, commit

C# project, VS15, TFS15, xaml build.

I need my revision number to increase with every commit:

- I can't use the pre-commit hooks since some push through Visual Studio which doesn't support them
- I can't use the built-in version control (the [1.0.*]) since we have a different template.

**Question: is it possible to still increment the version before each commit (and if not, how can I make TFS commit the project with the increased version.**

Best case: Some way to increment version before each commit that does NOT involve git hooks (or make hooks work with VS?)

Second-best case: CI is triggered by a push, it increases the revision number (using a pre-build powershell script), pushes it back as a new commit (maybe in the same pre-build script?) and then builds the solution. 
(Yes, I know this is ugly but I can turn the CI off and only a manual build increases the version, which is okay.)

Third-best: Something else entirely?

Comment: vs15 and visual studio 2015 update 3 support pre-commit hooks. As long as bash and all the unix tools are in the path, you should be golden.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your Best Case, except change the version manually or run script locally, I can't think out any other way.

For your Second Case, using a pre-build powershell script to increase the revision number and push it back is possible. But in this way, you will always have a new commit.

The workaround I can think out is increasing the revision during build. Or else you may need to change the revision manually.

Comment: I figured the same, I ended up setting it up so a build is triggered manually and a new commit is made each time the project is built.